# Trigger (not updating automatically) only updating field when editing and saving record

Tags: trigger, field-update

I have created a trigger to update a custom field "Net Amount" (NetAmount__c) anytime the value of the standard field "Order Amount" (TotalAmount) is updated.
The problem I face is that the field NetAmount__c only updates when I pretend to edit the record.

Let's say I add a product on my order (Order Amount: 120 000). The field Net Amount does not get updated automatically.

[image]

but if I click Edit then Save the record straight away without editing anything, the field (NetAmount__c) gets updated with the correct value.

[image]

I struggle to figure out why I have to click edit and save the record for the field to get updated

here is my trigger:

```
   trigger CalculMontant on Order (before update) {

   for(Order newOrder : Trigger.New) {
       if(newOrder.TotalAmount != null && newOrder.ShipmentCost__c != null) {
           newOrder.NetAmount__c = newOrder.TotalAmount - newOrder.ShipmentCost__c;
       }
   }    
}
```

Comment: if the field `order amount` is rollup, it won't trigger record update.

Comment: Once you add a product the new order amount is not calculated in before trigger and after trigger as well. You can achieve the same using the workflow field update